# Single webcam using /dev/video0 and /dev/video1

Tags: webcam, pi-4, raspbian-buster

With just one webcam attached, I get two devices: `/dev/video0` and `/dev/video1` They appear to have identical attributes. It's random which one gets bound to which entry, and only 1 of them actually works as a camera for OctoPrint. I need to uniquely identify the working entry in `/etc/udev/rules.d/99-usb.rules` so that the working entry is the only one bound to `/dev/videoside`

```
pi@octopi:~ $ ls -al /dev/video*
crw-rw---- 1 root video 81, 3 Jul  7 16:08 /dev/video0
crw-rw---- 1 root video 81, 4 Jul  7 16:08 /dev/video1
crw-rw---- 1 root video 81, 0 Jul  7 16:08 /dev/video10
crw-rw---- 1 root video 81, 1 Jul  7 16:08 /dev/video11
crw-rw---- 1 root video 81, 2 Jul  7 16:08 /dev/video12
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      6 Jul  7 16:08 /dev/videoside -> video1
```

`udevadm info -n /dev/video0`

```
P: /devices/platform/scb/fd500000.pcie/pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0/0000:01:00.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4:1.0/video4linux/video0
N: video0
L: 0
S: v4l/by-path/platform-fd500000.pcie-pci-0000:01:00.0-usb-0:1.4:1.0-video-index0
S: v4l/by-id/usb-046d_HD_Pro_Webcam_C920_DE98DD8F-video-index0
S: videoside
E: DEVPATH=/devices/platform/scb/fd500000.pcie/pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0/0000:01:00.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4:1.0/video4linux/video0
E: DEVNAME=/dev/video0
E: MAJOR=81
E: MINOR=3
E: SUBSYSTEM=video4linux
E: USEC_INITIALIZED=4880816
E: ID_V4L_VERSION=2
E: ID_V4L_PRODUCT=HD Pro Webcam C920
E: ID_V4L_CAPABILITIES=:capture:
E: ID_VENDOR=046d
E: ID_VENDOR_ENC=046d
E: ID_VENDOR_ID=046d
E: ID_MODEL=HD_Pro_Webcam_C920
E: ID_MODEL_ENC=HD\x20Pro\x20Webcam\x20C920
E: ID_MODEL_ID=082d
E: ID_REVISION=0011
E: ID_SERIAL=046d_HD_Pro_Webcam_C920_DE98DD8F
E: ID_SERIAL_SHORT=DE98DD8F
E: ID_TYPE=video
E: ID_BUS=usb
E: ID_USB_INTERFACES=:0e0100:0e0200:010100:010200:
E: ID_USB_INTERFACE_NUM=00
E: ID_USB_DRIVER=uvcvideo
E: ID_PATH=platform-fd500000.pcie-pci-0000:01:00.0-usb-0:1.4:1.0
E: ID_PATH_TAG=platform-fd500000_pcie-pci-0000_01_00_0-usb-0_1_4_1_0
E: ID_FOR_SEAT=video4linux-platform-fd500000_pcie-pci-0000_01_00_0-usb-0_1_4_1_0
E: DEVLINKS=/dev/v4l/by-path/platform-fd500000.pcie-pci-0000:01:00.0-usb-0:1.4:1.0-video-index0 /dev/v4l/by-id/usb-046d_HD_Pro_Webcam_C920_DE98DD8F-video-index0 /dev/videoside
E: TAGS=:uaccess:seat:
```

`udevadm info -n /dev/video1`

```
P: /devices/platform/scb/fd500000.pcie/pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0/0000:01:00.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4:1.0/video4linux/video1
N: video1
L: 0
S: v4l/by-id/usb-046d_HD_Pro_Webcam_C920_DE98DD8F-video-index1
S: v4l/by-path/platform-fd500000.pcie-pci-0000:01:00.0-usb-0:1.4:1.0-video-index1
S: videoside
E: DEVPATH=/devices/platform/scb/fd500000.pcie/pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0/0000:01:00.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4:1.0/video4linux/video1
E: DEVNAME=/dev/video1
E: MAJOR=81
E: MINOR=4
E: SUBSYSTEM=video4linux
E: USEC_INITIALIZED=4891214
E: ID_V4L_VERSION=2
E: ID_V4L_PRODUCT=HD Pro Webcam C920
E: ID_V4L_CAPABILITIES=:capture:
E: ID_VENDOR=046d
E: ID_VENDOR_ENC=046d
E: ID_VENDOR_ID=046d
E: ID_MODEL=HD_Pro_Webcam_C920
E: ID_MODEL_ENC=HD\x20Pro\x20Webcam\x20C920
E: ID_MODEL_ID=082d
E: ID_REVISION=0011
E: ID_SERIAL=046d_HD_Pro_Webcam_C920_DE98DD8F
E: ID_SERIAL_SHORT=DE98DD8F
E: ID_TYPE=video
E: ID_BUS=usb
E: ID_USB_INTERFACES=:0e0100:0e0200:010100:010200:
E: ID_USB_INTERFACE_NUM=00
E: ID_USB_DRIVER=uvcvideo
E: ID_PATH=platform-fd500000.pcie-pci-0000:01:00.0-usb-0:1.4:1.0
E: ID_PATH_TAG=platform-fd500000_pcie-pci-0000_01_00_0-usb-0_1_4_1_0
E: ID_FOR_SEAT=video4linux-platform-fd500000_pcie-pci-0000_01_00_0-usb-0_1_4_1_0
E: DEVLINKS=/dev/v4l/by-id/usb-046d_HD_Pro_Webcam_C920_DE98DD8F-video-index1 /dev/v4l/by-path/platform-fd500000.pcie-pci-0000:01:00.0-usb-0:1.4:1.0-video-index1 /dev/videoside
E: TAGS=:uaccess:seat:
```

It's not specific to this camera. I have the same issue with another Logitech c920, as well as two LEOTAD brand webcams. Each of the 4 cameras results in two /dev/video* devices.

Raspbian Buster on a Pi 4 using this OctoPi image: https://storage.googleapis.com/octoprint/2019-06-24_2019-06-20-octopi-buster-lite-0.17.0.zip

Comment: I have similar issue on buster, attaching a webcam creates 2 device entries, but only 1 works. I did not have this problem on strech and jessie. Tried reinstalling buster, but ended up with the same result

Comment: Had the same problem, answered it here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/581838/408072